# How to check which user a certain process belongs to?

Tags: ubuntu, process

I am using server with others users. Sometime a process is dead but it still occupy GPU, so I need to remind the user. How can I find that user  ? Thanks for any suggestions .

Answer (score 0):

The command `ps aux`, in its leftmost column lists the user associated with the process that is listed in its rightmost column.

If you know the name of the program, you might faster get there by issuing: `ps au -C <process_name>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  When I input: ps aux, the output process is too much to find the one I want (maybe it contains many system process). I am trying to use:     ps au -C <process_name>, but the output is the same as:     ps aux